# Ubuntu USB Installation Medium Can't Detect Hard Drive

Tags: system-installation, usb-installation

I just purchased a new laptop, and am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 via a USB stick - something I've done on five other computers. However, when I got to the step where you pick a target to install to... there were no options listed. Running the OS off the USB stick and accessing the terminal, when I run 'sudo lsblk' the only disk I see is the USB stick.

It came with windows, and I was going to do a duel boot install. I've tried everything I can find related to windows issues and nothing works there. I finally used Windows USB boot media to start the install process, delete all the partitions on the disk when asked where I wanted to install windows, and then quit the install and tried installing Ubuntu again. It still can't detect the disk.

The BIOS menu has a surprisingly minimal set of options available, and I've been working with those per advice I found online but nothing seems to help. Returning this laptop is going to be very difficult, but it's useless to me without a linux build installed. My job and grad school are all data analysis and machine learning, and Windows just isn't an option.

These are the machine specs:

MSI Laptop Creator 17 B11UH-241
Intel Core i9 11th Gen 11900 H (2.50GHz)
32GB Memory
1 TB NVMe SSD NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Laptop GPU

The very detailed specs:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/systems-devices/sku/h93150871/msi-creator-17-b11uh241/specifications.html

Anyone have any thoughts?

I'm inserting some photos (sorry) of the bios interface so my limited options are visible:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Find some settings for drive mode (not necessarily spelt this way) and change whatever mode it comes with by default (RAID, Intel RST, ...) and change it to AHCI. This should be all to get the drive recognized. However, considering you won't be using Windows 11 go ahead and disable Secure Boot.

Comment: I can't find anything like that. That was a common recommendation that I found via web searches. It's the most minimal bios I've ever seen. I'll take some photos of the bios screens and append them. I'm beginning to fear that there are options I need to change that are just hard-coded in.

Comment: There are a few firmwares that give access to additional features only when a administrator/supervisor password is enabled. I don't know if applicable here, check your manual. If you decide to try make sure to NEVER forget it or you'd be locked out. UEFI password can only be reset by tech support unlike old BIOS passwords.

Comment: After an hour chatting with baffled support at MSI, they ended up finding out that you CAN'T switch to AHCI. It's locked into Intel RST... Is it possible to install ubuntu with that setting?

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't (yet) possible.

Comment: I ended up returning the machine. I can't do the work I do on Windows. It seems a little ridiculous that that functionality wouldn't be available on such a high-end laptop. Or any laptop.

Comment: Can you please add a photo of the installer screen where you are getting stuck?